# Handle multiple requests with different parameters in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I generated the actions and reducers communicating with my backend. I do this with the help of a swagger.json which provides all the backend-definitions I need.

Whenever I call an endpoint like `/customers?get=all` the result is stored in `state.customers.getCustomersData`. At the same time I call `/customers?get=some` which causes redux to store the result also in `state.customers.getCustomersData`, because it's the same endpoint.

Are there any best practices dealing with these kinds of issues?

Comment: I would say get all the customers data at once in the reducers state and any further call, fetch that data from the redux store rather than making an API call\

Comment: What type of data is stored at `customers.getCustomersData`? An array, an object?  If you don't want to fetch all the customer data at once like @ShubhamKhatri suggested, you can always store it as a map/object and then just merge the data at `customers.getCustomersData` anytime the endpoint is called.

Comment: thank you for your answer. In this example `getCustomersData` is an array and fetching all data and filtering it later on seems like the best idea.
What if I have `/customer?id=1` and `/customer?id=2` calls and want to display these at the same time? The data would be overwritten by the second call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright - here is my solution.
I will pass an optional parameter to the action derterminating the key of the action - this way I can control datakeys within the store.